# Search in a multidimensional assoc array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an array, looking like this:

```
[lund] => Array
    (
        [69] => foo
    )

[berlin] => Array
    (
        [138] => foox2
    )

[tokyo] => Array
    (
        [180] => foox2
        [109] => Big entrance
        [73] => foo
    )
```

The thing is that there were duplicate keys, so I re-arranged them so I can search more specifically, I thought.

Previously I could just

```
$key = array_search('foo', $array);
```

to get the key but now I don't know how.

**Question**: I need key for value `foo`, from `tokyo`. How do I do that?

Comment: What do you know, the key `tokyo` and the value or only the value (which could cause duplicates...)?

Comment: so you need last searched item?

Comment: I know `tokyo` and `foox2` and `Big entrance` and `foo`, but not the keys of them. I want to search after the key in tokyo with value foo, for example.

Comment: So use `array_search` in just a part of your array to get the inner key: `$key = array_search('foo', $array['tokyo']);`

Comment: you can hard code index tokyo in array_search function

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through array, since its 2 dimensional in this case. And then find corresponding value.

```
foreach($arr as $key1 => $key2 ) {
      foreach($key2 as $k => $value) {
        if($value == "foo") {
            echo "{$k} => {$value}";
        }
    }
}
```

This example match key with `$value`, but you can do match with `$k` also, which in this case is `$key2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all `keys` and `value` of `foo` by using this:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $newArr[$key] = array_search('foo', $value);
}
print_r(array_filter($newArr));
```

**Result is:**

```
Array
(
    [lund] => 69
    [tokyo] => 109
)
```

If you don't mind about the hard code than you can use this:

```
array_search('foo', $array['tokyo']);
```

It just a simple example, you can modify it as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Since **Question**: I need key for value foo, from tokyo. How do i do that?

```
$key = array_search('foo', $array['tokyo']);
```

As a function:

```
function getKey($keyword, $city, $array) {
    return array_search($keyword, $array[$city]);
}
// PS. Might be a good idea to wrap this array in an object and make getKey an object method.
```

If you want to get all cities (for example to loop through them):

```
$cities = array_keys($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$a = array(
        "land"=> array("69"=>"foo"),
        "land1"=> array("138"=>"foo1"),
        "land2"=> array('180' => 'foox2',
        '109' => 'Big entrance',
        '73' => 'foo'),
    );
//print_r($a);
$reply = search_in_array($a, "foo");
print_r($reply);


function search_in_array($a, $search)
{
    $result = array();
    foreach($a as $key1 => $array ) {
          foreach($array as $k => $value) {
            if($value == "$search") {
                array_push($result,"{$key1}=>{$k}");
                breck;
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will return the key or null if the search value is not found.

```
function search($searchKey, $searchValue, $searchArr)
{
    foreach ($searchArr as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == $searchKey && in_array($searchValue, $value)) {
            $results = array_search($searchValue, $value);
        }
    }

    return isset($results) ? $results : null;
}
// var_dump(search('tokyo', 'foo', $array));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');


$array=array("lund" => array
(
    69 => "foo"
),

"berlin" => array
(
    138 => "foox2"
),

"tokyo" => array
(
    180 => "foox2",
    109 => "Big entrance",
    73 => "foo"
));



function search($array, $arrkey1, $arrvalue2){

  foreach($array as $arrkey=>$arrvalue){

     if($arrkey == $arrkey1){

      foreach($arrvalue as $arrkey=>$arrvalue){

        if(preg_match("/$arrvalue/i",$arrvalue2))
           return $arrkey;

         }

       }     

     }


   }

   $result=search($array, "tokyo", "foo"); //$array=array; tokyo="inside array to check"; foo="value" to check
   echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

I created solution using array iterator. Have a look on below solution:

```
$array = array(
    'lund' => array
    (
        '69' => 'foo'
    ),

    'berlin' => array
    (
        '138' => 'foox2'
    ),

    'tokyo' => array
    (
        '180' => 'foox2',
        '109' => 'Big entrance',
        '73' => 'foo'
    )
);

$main_key = 'tokyo'; //key of array
$search_value = 'foo'; //value which need to be search

$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));

foreach ($iterator as $key => $value) {
    $keys = array();
    if ($value == $search_value) {
        $keys[] = $key;
        for ($i = $iterator->getDepth() - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
            $keys[] = $iterator->getSubIterator($i)->key();
        }

        $key_paths = array_reverse($keys);
        if(in_array($main_key, $key_paths) !== false) {
            echo "'{$key}' have '{$value}' value which traverse path is: " . implode(' -> ', $key_paths) . '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

you can change value of `$main_key` and `$serch_value` according to your parameter. hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$lund = [
    '69' => 'foo'
];
$berlin = [
    '138' => 'foox2'
];
$tokyo = [
    '180' => 'foox2',
    '109' => 'Big entrance',
    '73' => 'foo'
];
$array = [
    $lund,
    $berlin,
    $tokyo
];

echo $array[2]['180']; // outputs 'foox2' from $tokyo array
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get `key` by `specific key` and `value` then your code should be:

```
function search_array($array, $key, $value)
{
    if(is_array($array[$key])) {
        return array_search($value, $array[$key]);
    }
}

echo search_array($arr, 'tokyo', 'foo');
```